# Deploying test server with git

Tags: git, deployment, webhooks

I have two folders on my server, one for test and one for production. I have a git repository with two branches and a webhook on the server activated when i push. I want my code in the 'test' folder to be updated with the branch 'test' when i push to that branch and then when im ready make the code updated in the production folder. Whats the best way to do it with git? In the .sh file on the server should i put

```
git pull origin test
```

Or should i use another command like fetch? And then when the modifies are ok should i make push to the master or merge the branches?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to clone the repo afresh and then checkout the relevant branch?

Comment: Why? @evolutionxbox

Comment: So you're guaranteed to have the latest code, without the risk of needing to merge or fix conflicts (like when using pull).